# I cant read my text files from my application's Bundle

Tags: swift, file, text, bundle, nsfilemanager

I used to read the text files from my application's bundle by using the following code. However, no matter what my application can't find them anymore. I am 100% sure that all my files are in the Assets.xcassets, I can see them, edit them, transform them from a directory to another. But my application doesn't want to read them, please tell me what I missed!!

this is the procedure I am using...

```
func readBundle(file:String) -> String
{
    var res: String = ""
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "txt")
    {
        let fm = NSFileManager()
        let exists = fm.fileExistsAtPath(path)
        if(exists)
        {
            let c = fm.contentsAtPath(path)
            res = NSString(data: c!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as! String
        }
    }
    return res
}
```

I am using it like this:

```
let res = readBundle("test")
print(res)
```

Comment: I'm not sure that storing those text files as Assets is the way to go. I'd stick with @Pyro''s answer for all kinds of bundle resources that are not artwork.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30808846/2303865

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548771/swift-how-do-i-get-the-file-path-inside-a-folder/34548888?s=2|1.1752#34548888

Answer (score 4):

when storing non image files in XCAssets, you should use NSDataAsset to acccess their content

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSDataAsset_Class/

```
func readBundle(file:String) -> String
{
    var res = ""
    if let asset = NSDataAsset(name: file) ,
        string = String(data:asset.data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){
        res = string
    }
    return res
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In the another option then 'XCAssets' you can create a separate folder/group of your resources other than images in the project structure, check if they exist in the `Copy Bundle Resource` in the Build phases section of your project's main target

If you add resource like this your current code should work as it is

```
func readBundle(file:String) -> String
{
    var res: String = ""
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(file, ofType: "txt")
    {
       //you should be able to get the path
       //other code as you has written in the question
    }
    return res
}
```

Comment: I wanted, but stackoverflow.com doesnt allow me to do so yest since I am new